# Detect a broken link (web) in perl

Tags: perl, lwp, broken-links

I'm trying to detect if a link is broken or not, as in if it's a web address I could paste into my browser and find a web page. I've tried two methods so far that I found online and both are giving me false positives (LWP::UserAgent and LWP::Simple).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url1 = 'http://www.gutenberg.org';
my $url2 = 'http://www.gooasdfzzzle.com.no/thisisnotarealsite';


my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0");  # Pretend to be Mozilla

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "$url1");
my $res = $ua->request($req);

if ($res->is_success) {
    print "Success!\n";
} else {
    print "Error: " . $res->status_line . "\n";
}

$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "$url2");
$res = $ua->request($req);

if ($res->is_success) {
    print "Success!\n";
} else {
    print "Error: " . $res->status_line . "\n";
}
```

Which is giving me output of:

```
Success!
Success!
```

and then there's

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url1 = 'http://www.gutenberg.org';
my $url2 = 'http://www.gooasdfzzzle.com.no/thisisnotarealsite';

if (head("$url1")) {
    print "Yes\n";
} else {
    print "No\n";
}

if (head("$url2")) {
    print "Yes\n";
} else {
    print "No\n";
}
```

Which is giving me an output of:

```
Yes
Yes
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your code works for me. `perl lwp_test.pl
Success!
Error: 500 Can't connect to www.gooasdfzzzle.com.no:80 (Bad hostname)` Do you perhaps have a proxy or gateway service that is being "helpful" - I suggest you `print $res->content();` to get more clues.

Comment: @TylerHills `perl -v` ?

Comment: Works fine on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me, I can only see a problem if your running behind a VPN or gateway as previous stated. Always use `strict` and `warnings`, and here is an alternative way so you are not initializing a new Request object everytime you want to check for a valid link.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use LWP::UserAgent; 

sub check_url { 
  my ($url) = @_; 
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(HEAD => $url);
  my $res = $ua->request($req); 
  return $res->status_line if $res->is_error;
  return "Success: $url"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm guessing it's my firewall, when I go to a page that looks correct like 'http://notarealaddressever.notreal' it directs me to a page telling me they couldn't find that page, so that is probably causing it to not fail.